# Explorer passing the full executable path name in its command line arguments

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, explorer

I created a new **Win32 Console Application**. It has this main entry point:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
```

I am parsing parameters in `lpCmdLine`:

```
LPWSTR *szArglist;
int nArgs;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &nArgs);
if (nArgs >= 1 && wcslen(szArglist[0]) > 0)
    productName = szArglist[0];
if (nArgs >= 2 && wcslen(szArglist[1]) > 0 && PathFileExists(szArglist[1]))
    installPath = szArglist[1];
```

I want to parse the first parameter as `productName` and the second parameter as `installPath`. However, if I launch this program from `explorer`, it sets the first parameter as the full path to the executable.

Is there any way to handle this behavior? Under what situations does Windows pass arguments to my application? How can I ignore these, and have my application accept command line arguments as follows:

```
application.exe "Product Name" "C:\Program Files\Product Name"
```

Comment: The 1st parameter is just what was used when creating the process. If you  type "calc.exe" in console, the 1st parameter of the calc process will be just that.

Comment: Obligatory [OldNewThing link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060515-07/?p=31203/). And [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100916-00/?p=12843).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just need to change my approach by parsing for named arguments:

```
LPWSTR *szArglist;
int nArgs;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &nArgs);
BOOL skipNext = false;
for (int i = 0; i < nArgs; i++) {
    if (skipNext) {
        skipNext = false;
        continue;
    }
    if (wcscmp(szArglist[i], L"/path") == 0 && i + 1 < nArgs && wcslen(szArglist[i + 1]) > 0 && PathFileExists(szArglist[i + 1])) {
        installPath = szArglist[i + 1];
        skipNext = true;
    }
    if (wcscmp(szArglist[i], L"/product") == 0 && i + 1 < nArgs && wcslen(szArglist[i + 1]) > 0) {
        productName = szArglist[i + 1];
        skipNext = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, parsing named arguments is the usual approach to do it. But note what [Raymond Chen writes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100916-00/?p=12843): _The first parameter to CommandLineToArgvW is supposed to be the value returned by GetCommandLineW_

Comment: @zett42 Do you know that Raymond is actually quite active on this site? He's posted some useful answers to some of my questions.

Comment: @zett42 Wait, are you Raymond Chen in disguise?